# Webpack - Transform modern CSS functions

Tags: javascript, css, webpack

Have a webpack configuration with [css-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader) and [postcss-loader](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-loader) for autoprefixer.

Everything works however now I wanted to be able to use the modern functions of the CSS : var(), calc(), repeat()...

Is there a loader webpack that would allow me to rewrite these functions in order to be able to use them on all browsers ?

**input:**

```
:root {
 --X: 40px;
}

.body-test {
 transform: translateX(var(--X));
 padding: calc(var(--X) + 60px);
 margin: repeat(4, 20px);
}
```

**output:**

```
.body-test {
 transform: translateX(40px);
 padding: 100px;
 margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}
```

Thanks you very much !

Comment: what issue are you facing?

Comment: I would suggest using a CSS pre-compiler like [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/).

Comment: with postcss you can use -> http://cssnext.io/

Comment: Thanks Keith, cssnext seems perfect.